# python subprocess("cmd") spawning another interactive shell

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

```
import os, subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print>>p.stdin, "echo hi"
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
print>>p.stdin, "python"
p.stdout.readline()
```

Now, if I do `p.stdout.readline()`, why don't I see a python shell?

On the other hand, If instead of `python`, I had started another `cmd` from the subprocess, I can see a new `cmd` shell spawning.

```
import os, subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
print>>p.stdin, "echo hi"
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
print>>p.stdin, "cmd"
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
p.stdout.readline()
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python behaves differently when its standard output is not a terminal device: no prompt, no banner, it just reads a complete script and executes it.

I don't know exactly how it was ported to Windows, but "console handle" is the closes thing to "terminal device" they have.

Comment: that doesn't help me. I want the second behavior in the first case.

Comment: Using `python -i` could help

Comment: Nope. After using `python -i`, still the same behavior

Comment: @prongs just checked: python writes banner & prompt to stderr, not stdout. (so you need both `python -i` to get it print these things, and use `p.stderr.readline()` to see them (or use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to redirect both))

Comment: What difference does the `-i` make?

Comment: It forces python into interactive mode even if it's input is a pipe. (Tested on linux with python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2. Documentation is unclear on stand-alone -i)